# CSS flex layout in absolute container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I have the following HTML/CSS that has a container (`.full-width.section3`) which has an absolute height. However, centering the content within does not work. Since I am new to the flex model, could someone explain to me, why the three child `div`s are not centered vertically?

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;     
  height:100vh;
  background-color: white;
}
.full-width {
  width:100%;              
}

.full-width.section3{
 height: 795px;
}

.full-width > .content > .third-parent{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.full-width > .content > .third-parent > .third{
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.full-width > .content > .third-parent > .third > img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.middle-text{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


.full-width > .content > .third-parent > .third > .middle-text > .list-div2{
    display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.full-width > .content > .third-parent > .third > .middle-text > .list-div2  li{
   position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  visibility: visible;
}

.list-div2 li::before{
  content: '\2022';
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.items-list2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="full-width section3">
    <div class="content">
       <div class="third-parent">
         <div class="third" id="one">
           <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=right">
          </div>
        <div class="third" id="two">
          <div class="middle-text">
            <h1>Some headline</h1>
                  <div class="list-div2">
        <ul class="items-list2" id="list">
          <li>Entry A</li>
          <li>Entry B</li>
          <li>Entry C</li>
          <li>Entry D</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third" id="three">
          <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=left">
        </div>
         </div>
       </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I´m not completly sure if I understand what you are doing there. Why are your images or the "middle-text" positioned absolute? I think there already starts your problem.
to center vertically you furthermore need "align-items: center;" - but you need this on the flex-wrapper and not the child

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing flex with absolute positioning. This breaks flex for children elements:

> As it is out-of-flow, an absolutely-positioned child of a flex
>   container does not participate in flex layout.

source: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clear on what it is you are trying to achieve but flex layout does not lend itself to absolute positioned children

If centering is the issue then there are option available to you in flexbox.

```
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}

.full-width.section3 {
  height: 795px;
}

.full-width>.content>.third-parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.full-width>.content>.third-parent>.third {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.full-width>.content>.third-parent>.third>img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.full-width>.content>.third-parent>.third>.middle-text>.list-div2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.full-width>.content>.third-parent>.third>.middle-text>.list-div2 li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  visibility: visible;
}

.list-div2 li::before {
  content: '\2022';
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.items-list2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="full-width section3">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="third-parent">
        <div class="third" id="one">
          <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=right">
        </div>
        <div class="third" id="two">
          <div class="middle-text">
            <h1>Some headline</h1>
            <div class="list-div2">
              <ul class="items-list2" id="list">
                <li>Entry A</li>
                <li>Entry B</li>
                <li>Entry C</li>
                <li>Entry D</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third" id="three">
          <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=left">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove position: absolute; to class middle-text and add display: inline; to centered the middle column

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;     
  height:100vh;
  background-color: white;
}
.full-width {
  width:100%;              
}

.full-width.section3{
 height: 795px;
}

.full-width > .content > .third-parent{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.full-width > .content > .third-parent > .third{
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.full-width > .content > .third-parent > .third > img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.middle-text{
  width: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: auto;
  display: inline;
}


.full-width > .content > .third-parent > .third > .middle-text > .list-div2{
    display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.full-width > .content > .third-parent > .third > .middle-text > .list-div2  li{
   position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  visibility: visible;
}

.list-div2 li::before{
  content: '\2022';
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.items-list2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="full-width section3">
    <div class="content">
       <div class="third-parent">
         <div class="third" id="one">
           <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=right">
          </div>
        <div class="third" id="two">
          <div class="middle-text">
            <h1>Some headline</h1>
                  <div class="list-div2">
        <ul class="items-list2" id="list">
          <li>Entry A</li>
          <li>Entry B</li>
          <li>Entry C</li>
          <li>Entry D</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third" id="three">
          <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=left">
        </div>
         </div>
       </div>
</div>
</div>
```